# Convert two date columns from two different tables into one in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to make a query in sql server.. I have two tables

`Table#1`:

```
Id -- OneDate -- HoursWork
1 -- 25/04/2014 -- 5
2 -- 26/04/2014 -- 7
```

`Table#2`:

```
Id -- ADate -- HoursRest
1 -- 25/04/2014 -- 5
```

I want a query with this result

```
Id -- Date -- HoursWork -- HoursRest
1 -- 25/04/2014 -- 5 -- 5
2 -- 26/04/2014 -- 7 -- 0
```

As you can see I need to match by id and by date.

Comment: What query you tried so far??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT table1.id
, table1.onedate
, table1.hourswork
, ISNULL(table2.hoursrest, 0)
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
```

Comment: yeah.. `ISNULL(table2.hoursrest, 0)` this was missing

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.date, table1.HoursWork, table2.HoursRest 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.id = table2.id 
WHERE table1.OneDate = table2.ADate`
```

Comment: Yeah but only appears the one that has the two values

Comment: @Golgothan3: Please provide concise but descriptive explanations with your answers. It helps to clarify, educate and thus improves overall quality of this site for current and future users.